# SQL count() over 2 tables by a type

Tags: sql, count, sql-order-by

I have a question how to make the right sql statement, because I have no Idea how to start ;-(

There are the following two tables:

Table 1: test

```
id|name|type
-------------
1|FirstUnit|1
2|FirstWeb|2
3|SecondUnit|1
```

Table 2: types

```
id|type
--------
1|UnitTest
2|WebTest
```

I would like to get the following result:

Table result:

```
type|amount
-----------
UnitTest|2
WebTest|1
```

Can anyone helping with giving a hint how to start?

Thanks in advance.
LStrike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this query:

```
SELECT
    t.type ,
    COUNT(*) AS amount
FROM types AS t
   JOIN test AS te ON t.id= te.type
GROUP BY type
ORDER BY t.type
```

Comment: Any time :) Our purpose is to gave you possible correct answer as soon as possible

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  a.type, COUNT(b.type) amount
FROM    types a
        LEFT JOIN test b
            ON a.ID = b.type
GROUP   BY a.type
ORDER   BY amount DESC
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/33b30/2)

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: thank you for the fast answer and the link, will read it. Can't mark both as correct and working ;-(

Comment: the problem with your accepted answer is that it will not show the type that has no record on test table, example http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dc7e37/1

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:-

```
 SELECT  types.type, COUNT(test.type) as amount from types,test where test.type=types.id 
 GROUP BY test.type
 ORDER BY amount
```