# Using @DECLARE in MYSQL 5.1

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

just playing around with some sql statements on MYSQL Server 5.1
I already asked a question how to make a specific count on two tables (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807635/sql-count-over-2-tables-by-a-type/15807676?noredirect=1#comment22483634_15807676))
and I also found an answer how to transpose my result (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8429442/transposing-a-table-in-sql-server/14308741?noredirect=1#comment22486399_14308741)) but I cant use it on my local MYSQL Server 5.1.

This is table one: test

```
id|name|test_type
-------------
1|FirstUnit|1
2|FirstWeb|2
3|SecondUnit|1
```

The second table: test_type

```
id|type
--------
1|UnitTest
2|WebTest
```

The following result will be written into "yourtable" (a temporary table)

```
type|amount
-----------
UnitTest|2
WebTest|1
```

What I want to have at the end is:

```
UnitTest|WebTest
-----------------
2|1
```

(The problem is I think, the the last part is from an MS-SQL example, so it will not work on MYSQL)

This are my sql statements:

```
--create a temporary table
create temporary table IF NOT EXISTS yourtable
(
test_type varchar(255),
amount varchar(255)
);

--make a selecten into the temporary table 
INSERT INTO yourtable
SELECT
    t.test_type ,
    COUNT(*) AS amount

FROM test_types AS t
   JOIN test AS te ON t.id= te.test_type
GROUP BY test_type
ORDER BY t.test_type;


--just for debugging
select * from yourtable;


-- transpose result
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Type) 
                    from yourtable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select Type, Amount,
                  row_number() over(partition by Type order by Type, Amount) rn
                from yourtable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(Amount)
                for Type in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)

--drop temporary table
drop table yourtable;
```

I can't run the last part where I want to transpose my temporary result. I get an error for "DECLARE"

> /* SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
>       @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
>
> select @cols = ' at line 2 */ /* 2 rows affected, 2 rows found.
>   Duration for 3 of 4 queries: 0,000 sec. */

Can anybody help?

Comment: Can you edit your OP with some sample data and then the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL Does not have a *pivot* function so you will have to transpose the data from rows into columns using an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression:

```
select 
  sum(case when tt.type = 'UnitTest' then 1 else 0 end) UnitTest,
  sum(case when tt.type = 'WebTest' then 1 else 0 end) WebTest
from test t
inner join test_type tt
  on t.test_type = tt.id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c5159/3).

If you are going to have an unknown number of `types` that you want to convert to columns, you can use a prepared statement to generate dynamic SQL:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'sum(CASE WHEN tt.type = ''',
      type,
      ''' THEN 1 else 0 END) AS `',
      type, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM test_type;

SET @sql 
  = CONCAT('SELECT ', @sql, ' 
            from test t
            inner join test_type tt
              on t.test_type = tt.id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c5159/6)

Comment: thank you, do I always have to work like this, or is there a more general way to make a transposition? For example if there is added a new test type [ edit -- to slow ;-) ]